# VS Code not recognizing make

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, makefile

I get the following error when I try to debug a C++ program in VS Code:

```
> Executing task: make <

Starting build...
make
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Build finished with error(s).
The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1).
```

Comment: This is most likely an install issue. The instructions will differ depending on your OS. If this is linux you would typically use your package manager to install the tools for compiling or make directly.

Comment: Also I don't mean its a VSCode install issue. The issue is likely separate from VSCode as the tools for building c++ code are likely installed separately.

Comment: Should I reinstall C++ packages in VS Code then?